# Hessian under integral sign

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, hessian-matrix

If I have a function $f(a,b)$ s.t. $f(a,b)=\int_{I}{f(x,a,b)dx}$, how would I be able to characterize the point $(a^{*},b^{*})$ where $f(a^{*},b^{*})$ is an extremum? Would the Hessian simply be $$\begin{vmatrix}\int_{I}f_{aa}(x,a,b)dx&\int_{I}f_{ab}(x,a,b)dx\\\int_{I}f_{ba}(x,a,b)dx&\int_{I}f_{bb}(x,a,b)dx\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: What is $I$? Also you say it has a Hessian under integral sign, so does that imply $f(x,a,b)$ has any particular formula? Or is it just any function of $x$ with two parameters $a,b$?

Comment: @coffeemath $I$ is just the interval under which integration happen. $a,b$ are dynamical parameters going to some equilibrium. Essentially $\frac{da}{dt}=\int_{I}{f_{a}(x,a,b)}$, likewise for $\frac{db}{dt}$.

Comment: At (a*,b*) the two partials $f_a,f_b$ should be zero. I think the Hessian is for checking whether it'

Comment: @coffeemath That's what I want to know. Whether $(a^{*},b^{*})$ is a maximum or some other extremum.

Answer (score 1):

If $P=(a_0,b_0)$ is a critical point, i.e. solution of both $f_a=0$ and $f_b=0,$ AND the determinant of the Hessian at $P$ (what you have displayed, but with coordinates of critical point plugged in) is *positive,* then that tells you there is either a local max or a local min at $P.$ You have to look say at the first partials near $P$ to tell which. On the other hand if the Hessian determinant is negative there is a saddle point at $P$ so neither local max nor local min there. Finally a zero Hessian determinant gives no information, as one sees by a few examples.

Keep in mind all this is predicated on smoothness of $f(a,b)$ near $P,$ and that only the local max/min is decided, not the global or absolute max over whatever region $(a,b)$ ranges over.

Comment: So the Hessian I wrote is correct?

Comment: @Plinth It's right as far as where the second partials are placed. However I'm rusty on theorems about differentiating under the integral sign so that should be checked out.